# how to Load named router outlet in angular

Tags: angular, router-outlet

Below is my setup.

**app.component.html**

```
<p>App Component works!</p>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**activity.component.html**

```
<p>Activity Component Works!!<p>
<div> There are some other header controls present here, this HTML should render by default</div>
<router-outlet name="activity_router_outlet"></router-outlet>
```

**childa.component.html**

```
<p>ChildA Component Works!!<p>
```

**childb.component.html**

```
<p>ChildB Component Works!!<p>
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
{ 
    path: 'activity', 
    component: ActivityComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthenticateGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./activity/activity.module').then(m => m.ActivityModule) 
}
```

**activity-routing.module.ts**

```
{
    path: 'activity/childa',
    component: ChildAComponent,
    outlet: 'activity_router_outlet'
},
{
    path: 'activity/childb',
    component: ChildBComponent,
    outlet: 'activity_router_outlet'
}
```

when I to access below route **ChildA**.
http://localhost:4200/activity/childa
below is what i am expecting as output

```
App Component works! 
Activity Component Works!! 
There are some other header controls present here, this HTML should render by default
**ChildA** Component Works!!
```

when I to access below route **ChildB**.
http://localhost:4200/activity/childb
below is what i am expecting as output

```
App Component works! 
Activity Component Works!! 
There are some other header controls present here, this HTML should render by default
**ChildB** Component Works!!
```

I get below error. What am I not doing write. Please help

> Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'activity/childa'

**########################################################################**
**#############################Adding more info###########################**
**########################################################################**

[image: Here is my requirement]

I have some limitations on the routes, so the routes has to be exactly the same as i depicted in the image above.

Currently this is how my activity.component.html looks like

```
<p>Activity Component Works!!<p>
<app-activityheader></app-activityheader>
<app-childa *ngIf="_router.has.childa.in.the.url"></app-childa>
<app-childb *ngIf="_router.has.childb.in.the.url"></app-childb>
<app-childc *ngIf="_router.has.childc.in.the.url"></app-childc>
```

and the route config is as below, for any of the URL(shown in the image), I am loading the main AcitivityComponent and then handling the ChildComponent load in the HTML using *ngIf.

```
{
    path: 'activity/childa', component: ActivityComponent,
},
{
    path: 'activity/childb', component: ActivityComponent,
},
{
    path: 'activity/childc', component: ActivityComponent,
}
```

The downside of it is, everytime a visit the URL, all the components are reloaded. however i want the ActivityComponent and the ActivityHeaderComponent load only once and only the child components to be reloaded on demand.
What is the best way to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to check on your routing. Below steps will solve your problem

Change your routes config to

```json
     {
        path: 'childa',
        component: ChildaComponent,
        outlet: 'activity_router_outlet'
      },
      {
        path: 'childb',
        component: ChildbComponent,
        outlet: 'activity_router_outlet'
      }
```

I have simply removed the 'activity' prefix

Now in your links we can define them with

```
<a [routerLink]="['/activity',{ outlets: {primary: null, activity_router_outlet: 'childa'}}]">/activity/childA</a> <br />
<a [routerLink]="['/activity',{ outlets: {primary: null, activity_router_outlet: 'childb'}}]">/activity/childB</a>
```

[**Demo Here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6p5k2v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Thanks Owen for the info, I see the URL is:  
 **http://localhost:4200/activity/(activity_router_outlet:childa)**.                                            
 Is there any way i can render the child component as below url.  http://localhost:4200/activity/childa

Comment: You are using auxiliary routes, that is the routing url for auxiliary routes.  If you would like to use normal routing then remove the named router

Comment: Owen, I have added some more info the my question, could you please check and suggest me the best way to achieve this.